# If $\operatorname{Im}A + \operatorname{Im}B = \Bbb R^n$ then $\ker A \cap\ker B$ is not necessarily $\{0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A,B$ be square matrices of order $n\geq 2$. If $\operatorname{Im}A + \operatorname{Im}B = \Bbb R^n$, why $\textbf{can't}$ we say that $\ker A \cap \ker B = \{0\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no relation between the geometric *positions* of the kernel and the image of a linear map $V\to V$, just their *dimensions* are linked (as they are complementary) through the rank-nullity theorem. For instance, one can make a linear map $\def\R{\Bbb R}\R^2\to\R^2$ of rank $1$ (so one-dimensional kernel and image) with kernel the line given by the equation $ax+by=0$ and image given by the span of the nonzero vector $\binom cd$, by having its matrix be $$\pmatrix{c\\d}\pmatrix{a&b}=\pmatrix{ca&cb\\da&db}.$$
Now for $A$ and $B$ simply keep $a,b$ unchanged (so their kernels will be the same) and respectively take $\binom cd=\binom10$ for $A$ and $\binom cd=\binom01$ for $B$. That gives you the counterexamples, for any nonzero pair $(a,b)$
$$
  A=\pmatrix{a&b\\0&0},\qquad B=\pmatrix{0&0\\a&b}.
$$